# Glass material rendered as dark grey

Tags: materials, glass

I am trying to render a glass material on a cup. But it looks grey after rendering. Screenshot of the render. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNMEc.png)

The material details are as shown.Material details.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Z84.png)

Comment: You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page, instead of asking users go through links just to understand your question. Use the tools on the site to upload images directly. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question to modify it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png).

Comment: Make sure that the normals are facing in the right direction, screen space reflection should be enabled (*Render Properties*) and screen space refraction (*Material Properties*) as well. You should also have something in the environment that the glass can reflect, e.g. other objects or an environment map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the render settings. By default, *Eevee* does not calculate *Screen Space Reflections*, effectively disabling translucent/transparent materials.

You have two options, change to the *Cycles* render engine, or stick with *Eevee* and enable *Screen Space Reflections* and *Refraction*

[image]

Comment: Enabling the screen space reflection in Several did not help. However there is no penitentiary with cycles renderer.